# Windows 10: Thumbnails outline only are showing?

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, thumbnails, dark-mode

Recently on my Windows 10 Enterprise machine (Version 1809) my (pinned and non-pinned) taskbar thumbnails have stopped showing and only show an outline, this happens after a shutdown also. I have #6 *Sticky Notes* selected in the picture:

[image]

How can I get my thumbnails back showing?

Comment: What happens if you unpin and re-pin the items?

Comment: Even unpinned thumbnails are like this, so if I unpin one nothing happens....

Comment: try to [recreate the thumbnail cache](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-reset-thumbnail-cache-windows-10).

Comment: Thanks harrymc! The Disk Cleanup option did not work but recreating the thumbnails cache using Command Prompt as described in the link did, they are back. Please write up an answer and I will accept

Comment: Done as requested.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was a corruption of the thumbnail cache, and was fixed by method 2 below.

**Method 1 : Disk Cleanup**

- Enter `Disk Cleanup` in the Start menu and select
  "Clear disk space by deleting unnecessary f‌iles"
- Select the disk (default is `C:`)
- Ensure that "Thumbnails" is checked (the rest is up to you)
- Click OK and "Delete Files" to confirm.

**Method 2 : Command Prompt**

- Run the Command Prompt as administrator
- Stop Explorer by the command : `taskkill /f /im explorer.exe`
- The following command deletes all thumbnail caches without confirmation:

  ```
    del /f /s /q /a %LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer\thumbcache_*.db
  ```
- Restart Explorer : `start explorer.exe`